# How can I make vlc bind to all interfaces for streaming, but only loopback for the telnet interface?

Tags: vlc, streaming, video-streaming

The example from the documentation is:

```
vlc --ttl 12 -vvv --color -I telnet --telnet-password videolan --rtsp-host 0.0.0.0:5554
```

This, however, binds to all interfaces.  I would prefer not to mess with ipchains/iptables, but force it to only bind on loopback.  This would make it easier to manage from an automation of deployment perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`. That is, write:

```
vlc --ttl 12 -vvv --color -I telnet --telnet-password videolan --rtsp-host 127.0.0.1:5554
```